# Conexão com banco de dados por um arquivo externo (PHP)

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou fazendo um formulário e para isso criei um banco de dados onde tais dados serão salvos. Eu gostaria de fazer a conexão com o banco de dados a partir de um arquivo externo, dessa forma sendo necessário apenas chamá-lo com 'require' ou 'include'. Entretanto, quando feito isto, a variável de conexão '$con' passa nula, ou seja, eu não consigo usá-la. Creio que haja alguma forma para isso, porém, mesmo após várias pesquisas não encontrei nada que solucionasse isto.

Preciso de orientações sobre a possibilidade de tal. 
Obrigado desde já.

*Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\Users\Fulltime\Documents\Adaptando\php\cadastrar.php on line 25*

**servidor.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");

if (!$con) {
echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($con) . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

**cadastrar.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('php/servidor.php');
ini_set('display_errors',true); error_reporting(E_ALL);


    // Aqui são definidas as variáveis vindas do formulário
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];

    //aqui eu defino meu botão 
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {

    //  Aqui é executado a inserção no banco de dados
if (!empty($_POST['nome']) || !empty($_POST['email']) || !empty($_POST['telefone']) ||     !empty($_POST['cpf'])){

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO clientes(nomecli, emailcli, telefonecli, cpfcli) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$telefone', '$cpf')");
    if ($sql) {
            echo  "<script> 
            javascript:window.location='../cadastro.html';
            alert('Cadastrado realizado com sucesso!!!');</script>";
         exit;
    }

    else{
        echo "Opss!! Alguma coisa deu errado, cadastro não realizado.";
        exit;
    }
    }

    else{
    echo  "<script>javascript:window.location='../cadastro.html';
    alert('Opsss!! Algum dos campos está em branco, por favor, preencha-os.');</script>";
    exit;   
    }
}

else{
echo  "<script>alert('Opsss!! Botão não identificado.');</script>";
exit;
}

mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

O arquivo foi incluido com sucesso?

Comment: Estava incluído sim, o problema era outro, um amigo conseguiu me ajudar. Obrigado !!